# Wordpress translate pages option

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i want to create a same pages in wordpress but in different language. It should look like this:

[image]

So the language option will be in Pages panel like in image.

Can you please tell me how to do it or how does the plugin called? Thanks

Comment: Use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/

Answer (score 0):

You can try Lingotek Translation (`https://wordpress.org/plugins/lingotek-translation/`)

It's easy to use and I think is the one in the screenshot.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. But lingotek doesn't work like before. I used instead polylang.